# mysql only index for null / not null query

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a json column and I need to define the key length in order to index it.
I only need the index to quickly get me the values that are not null.
Should I just set the key length to 1?

Comment: "I only need the index to quickly get me the values that are not null" - depending on the queries and the data distribution, adding an index may be counter-productive for performance.

Comment: @symcbean most of the rows have null for this column

Comment: Then your schema design is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

When building a table with a `JSON` column, make sure to pull out data that needs to be heavily indexes; use a regular column and a regular index for it.

MySQL does not optimizer for null - not-null, except to lump all the null values together in the index.

Are you assuming that `"key":""` means "null"?  It looks like an empty string to me.  Having `key` missing from the json string might be equivalent to `NULL`.  Let's see your extraction code.

Comment: I did not mean null as a value within the json, but as the column value itself